# Trigger/sequence from Oracle to EntityFramework saving item gains ID?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, sequence

If I set up a trigger/sequence to get the nextval for a table would the object in my code gain the ID after it is saved?

Example:

```
using(TestContainer testContainer = new TestContainer()) {
    TestObj test = new TestObj;
    test.Name = "Test Object";
    testContainer.AddObject("TESTOBJ", test);
    testContainer.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(test, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
    testContainer.SaveChanges();
    System.Console.WriteLine("The test object ID is: " + test.ID);
}
```

The reason I want to know the ID of the new object is because the ID will be used as a reference for another object to know about the new TestObjet that was created.